# Is it possible to ignore characters in a string when matching with a regular expression

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nspredicate

I'd like to create a regular expression such that when I compare the a string against an array of strings, matches are returned with the regex ignoring certain characters.

Here's one example. Consider the following array of names:

```
{
    "Andy O'Brien",
    "Bob O'Brian",
    "Jim OBrien",
    "Larry Oberlin"
}
```

If a user enters "ob", I'd like the app to apply a regex predicate to the array and all of the names in the above array would match (e.g. the ' is ignored).

I know I can run the match twice, first against each name and second against each name with the ignored chars stripped from the string. I'd rather this by done by a single regex so I don't need two passes.

Is this possible? This is for an iOS app and I'm using NSPredicate.

**EDIT: clarification on use**

From the initial answers I realized I wasn't clear. The example above is a specific one. I need a general solution where the array of names is a large array with diverse names and the string I am matching against is entered by the user. So I can't hard code the regex like [o]'?[b].

Also, I know how to do case-insensitive searches so don't need the answer to focus on that. Just need a solution to ignore the chars I don't want to match against.

Comment: Since a regex is applied to each string in turn, you may simply remove all the chars you want to "ignore" from the strings, and then apply the regex to the modified strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have discarded all the answers showing the ways it can be done, you are left with the answer:

NO, this cannot be done. Regex does not have an option to 'ignore' characters. Your only options are to modify the regex to match them, or to do a pass on your source text to get rid of the characters you want to ignore and then match against that. (Of course, then you may have the problem of correlating your 'cleaned' text with the actual source text.)

Comment: I found a reasonable solution given my implementation, a variation of a pass through the source to eliminate the chars I don't want to match against. Thanks for your input.

Comment: That seems excessive to me. Why not take the search string, and indicate that the "ignored" characters may appear 0 or 1 times after every character? For example, if the user input the string "oleary", you could turn it into the regexp `o'?l'?e'?a'?r'?y'?` . I imagine this would have very negative effects on performance, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: that's the issue. this is a piece of code that needs to be as fast as possible. the solution I have now seems ok in that regard. thx.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want a way to match the characters "ob" 1) regardless of capitalization, and 2) regardless of whether there is an apostrophe in between them. That should be easy enough.

1) Use a case-insensitivity modifier, or use a regexp that specifies that the capital and lowercase version of the letter are both acceptable: `[Oo][Bb]`

2) Use the `?` modifier to indicate that a character may be present either one or zero times. `o'?b` will match both "o'b" and "ob". If you want to include other characters that may or may not be present, you can group them with the apostrophe. For example, `o['-~]?b` will match "ob", "o'b", "o-b", and "o~b".

So the complete answer would be `[Oo]'?[Bb]`.

**Update**: The OP asked for a solution that would cause the given character to be ignored in an arbitrary search string. You can do this by inserting `'?` after every character of the search string. For example, if you were given the search string `oleary`, you'd transform it into `o'?l'?e'?a'?r'?y'?`. Foolproof, though probably not optimal for performance. Note that this would match "o'leary" but also "o'lea'r'y'" if that's a concern.

Comment: thanks, please see my edit to the question. I need a more general solution.

Comment: If I understand the update correctly, you want to be able to search for a string while ignoring apostrophes. Is that right? Would it work to break the search string into characters, insert `'?` in between each one, and use the resulting string as a regexp?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, just throw the set of characters into the middle of the regex as optional. This works specifically because you have only two characters in your match string, otherwise the regex might get a bit verbose. For example, match case-insensitive against:

```
o[']*b
```

You can add more characters to that character class in the middle to ignore them. Note that the `*` matches *any* number of characters (so O'''Brien will match) - for a single instance, change to `?`:

```
o[']?b
```

Comment: thanks, please see my edit to the question. I need a more general solution.

Comment: @XJones: you're basically left with Phrogz's solution then, since you've changed the question around to invalidate everything else.

Comment: yeah, again, I apologize for being unclear. I wouldn't need SO for something that basic but I suppose you have no way of knowing that. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make particular characters optional with a question mark, which means that it will match whether they're there or not, e.g:

```
/o\'?b/
```

Would match all of the above, add `.+` to either side to match all other characters, and a space to denote the start of the surname:

```
/.+? o\'?b.+/
```

And use the case-insensitivity modifier to make it match regardless of capitalisation.